# How to unwrap an observable inside a map in rxjs?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

How can I unwrap the observable `(this.fireStore.getExtras(v["extrasId"]))`
inside the following map?

```
    this.authService
      .getUser()
      .pipe(
        flatMap((val) => this.fireStore.getItems(val.uid)),
        map((val) =>
          val.map((v) => ({ // this is regular array.map
            ...v,
            extras: {
              ...v["extras"],
              url: (this.fireStore.getExtras(v["extrasId"])).url // this is an observable. I want it to be unwrapped inside here itself,
            },
          }))
        )
      )
```

this is the inner observable to be unwrapped `(this.fireStore.getExtras(v["extrasId"]))`.
I tried `flatMap` but it is returning the function itself `..., url: flatmap() => ...`

Answer (score 0):

Untested

```
this.authService.getUser().pipe(
    flatMap(val => this.fireStore.getItems(val.uid)),
    switchMap(val => {
      return forkJoin(val.map(v => this.fireStore.getExtras(v.extrasId).pipe(map(x => ({...v, extras: {...v.extras, url: x.url}}))))),
    }),
);
```